# How to use python-dotenv's "find_dotenv" method

Tags: python

I've pip-installed the [python-dotenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dotenv) module and am trying to use it as follows. I've created a directory `test_dotenv` with the following tree:

```
.
├── config.env
└── test_dotenv_subdir
    └── test_dotenv.py
```

The `config.env` file is simply an empty file, while `test_dotenv.py` contains the following:

```
import dotenv

found_dotenv = dotenv.find_dotenv()
print(found_dotenv)
```

However, if I run this script using `python test_dotenv.py`, I find that nothing gets printed; that is, `found_dotenv` is an empty string (`''`).

Am I missing something about how to use this method? As far as I can tell, here is the relevant part of the [source code](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/tree/master/dotenv):

```
def _walk_to_root(path):
    """
    Yield directories starting from the given directory up to the root
    """
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        raise IOError('Starting path not found')

    if os.path.isfile(path):
        path = os.path.dirname(path)

    last_dir = None
    current_dir = os.path.abspath(path)
    while last_dir != current_dir:
        yield current_dir
        parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_dir, os.path.pardir))
        last_dir, current_dir = current_dir, parent_dir


def find_dotenv(filename='.env', raise_error_if_not_found=False, usecwd=False):
    """
    Search in increasingly higher folders for the given file

    Returns path to the file if found, or an empty string otherwise
    """
    if usecwd or '__file__' not in globals():
        # should work without __file__, e.g. in REPL or IPython notebook
        path = os.getcwd()
    else:
        # will work for .py files
        frame_filename = sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.co_filename
        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(frame_filename))

    for dirname in _walk_to_root(path):
        check_path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        if os.path.exists(check_path):
            return check_path

    if raise_error_if_not_found:
        raise IOError('File not found')

    return ''
```

It seems like `os.path.exists(check_path)` keeps on returning `False`, so that the in the end an empty string is returned. Why is this not working as intended?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `dotenv` package looks for a file that is literally called `.env` when you call `find_dotenv` rather than looking for files *like* `.env`. (e.g. `config.env`)

You can make your code find the desired file by passing the filename to `find_dotenv`, i.e.

```
import dotenv

found_dotenv = dotenv.find_dotenv('config.env')
print(found_dotenv)
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the find_dotenv to search in the current working directory, try giving the usecwd argument as true, as shown below:

```
dotenv_file = dotenv.find_dotenv(usecwd=True)
dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv_file)
```

So this searches for the '.env' file in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for that can be *.pyc files from another host stored in the project.

i.e. in my case, I copied the content of my repo into the container and start getting this error:

```
.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dotenv/main.py:257: in _walk_to_root
raise IOError('Starting path not found')
E   OSError: Starting path not found
```

I fixed it by running:

```
find . -name '*.pyc' | xargs rm -frv {} ;
```